# How to show output video of other application in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qtgui

I am creating a GUI application in Qt. This application is to display output of a application **X** which is not related to Qt hence i cant integrate it. **X** will output a video  . This video do not have a path since it is a real-time display of X output.

I want to show this output in Qt (along with some background GUI support).

So as far as my knowledge one way to do this is to get the window id of video and display that same window in QWidget. How to do this?

**EDIT :**

I am using Ubuntu.

I am able to get the window id by following command.

xwininfo -name  "name of window"

Comment: Yes, you can do that or you can pass window id of your application window to X and it'll output to that window instead of the _default_ one. So far **what did you try**?

Comment: Thank you . What i did is i have created a QWidget app. My another applications video output is ready. I want to show this video in QT widget only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the embed widget:

http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qx11embedwidget.html with a valid windowId

Comment: Thank you so much Wagmare. You gave exact answer.