# Play a Live video Stream using Qt

Tags: c++, qt, video, video-streaming

Given below is the code for playing a video file using Qt. Instead of playing the video I want to play a live video stream from an IP Camera. Another approach is to embed the VLC Player in Qt and a link for the project is provided [here](https://github.com/ntadej/vlc-qt). The problem is **I do not know how to include the player in Qt.** So how do I proceed?

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtMultimediaWidgets/QVideoWidget>
#include <QtMultimedia/QMediaPlayer>
#include <QtMultimedia/QMediaPlaylist>
#include <QFile>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include "DemoPlayer.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QWidget *widget=new QWidget;
    widget->resize(400,300);

    QMediaPlayer *player=new QMediaPlayer;
    QVideoWidget *vw= new QVideoWidget;
    QHBoxLayout *layout=new QHBoxLayout;

    layout->addWidget(vw);
    widget->setLayout(layout);
    player->setVideoOutput(vw);
    player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/1minute.mp4"));
    player->play();
    widget->show();
    qDebug()<<player->availableMetaData()<<player->currentMedia().canonicalUrl();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: The above code works just fine....please make your question a bit more clear

Comment: @Metoo check the question now.

Comment: Have you tried LibVLC https://wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC_SampleCode_Qt

Comment: @Metoo I have, cannot add it to the app, I am new to Qt so I don't know how to do so. If you know how to add it, then please tell me how to do it, or if there exists any tutorial tell me, because I cannot find any.

Comment: Are you on a system supporting X11 ie Linux, Mac (to some extent)? Btw the link provided by metoo is already a tutorial by itself...

Comment: Dont have qmake, and no, sadly on windows.

Answer (score 6):

follow this code . you can embed a widget inside another widget using a valid window id .
[How to show output video of other application in Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19975816/how-to-show-output-video-of-other-application-in-qt/19975877#19975877)
you can use the qx11embedwidget and qx11embedwidgetcontainer 
[QX11EmbedWidget and QX11EmbedContainer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102658/qx11embedwidget-and-qx11embedcontainer)

Comment: The link is not opening. Are you sure that its a valid link?

Comment: just check for qx11EmbedWidget and QX11EmbedContainer.. can you able to open the stack overflow thread ..?

Comment: I can open the thread but cannot open the link provided in the answer. That's the problem.

Comment: for me also . but you can start searching for QX11EmbedWidget. the required widget container you are looking for

Comment: The QX11EmbedWidget class provides an XEmbed client widget.

XEmbed is an X11 protocol that supports the embedding of a widget from one application into another application.

An XEmbed client widget is a window that is embedded into a container. A container is the graphical location that embeds (or swallows) an external application.

Comment: Ah, okay. I get it. Will read about it and come back to you if I have any problems. Thanks :)

Comment: What is the header file that I am supposed to use? I am using the normal #include <QX11EmbedContainer> as given in the documentation but it gives the error saying:No such file or Directory. What should I do?

Comment: your qt version ?. QWidget based application running on X11 better stay with Qt4. http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/54922-Qt5-and-embedwidgets

Comment: Qt 5.2.0, I downloaded it recently so...
Which Qt4 version do I need to use in order to use it?

Comment: sorry ..you cant do .. there is no replacement for qx11embedwidget in qt5  and plus.

Comment: So which Qt4 version do I use?

Comment: 4.8, 4.8.x any version .. there is even a sample application on QX11embedWidget for 4.8 in the link i send you recently . this one again http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/54922-Qt5-and-embedwidgets  12th reply

Comment: Check out this link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21527851/qx11embedcontainer-code-error

Another answer for you :P If you manage to solve it though