# QX11EmbedContainer code error

Tags: c++, qt, qx11embedcontainer

Given below is the code for embedding an application using QX11EmbedContainer.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QX11EmbedContainer>
#include <QProcess>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    QX11EmbedContainer container;
    container.show();

    QProcess process(&container);
    process.start("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop.../.exe");

    int status=a.exec();
    process.close();
    return status;
}
```

On running the application the error that I am getting is:

```
C:\Qt4.8.5\src\gui\kernel\qx11embed_x11.h:77: error: C2061: syntax error : identifier 'XEvent'
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QX11EmbedContainer is X11-specific, it will not work under other systems (like Windows).