# Qt Stream IP Camera Video

Tags: qt, video, network-programming

I am trying to stream the video from an IP camera using Qt multimedia (Qt 5).
A similar question could be found here: [Play a Live video Stream using Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21448027/play-a-live-video-stream-using-qt) but I try to avoid using an other library such as LibVLC.
I manage to display the video from a locally stored file but not to display the stream from the IP camera.

Here is my code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QMediaPlayer>
#include <qvideowidget.h>
#include <QVideoWidget>

#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this-> resize(1000,1000);
    QMediaPlayer *mp = new QMediaPlayer(0,0);
    QMediaContent *mc = new QMediaContent(QUrl("http://96.10.1.168/mjpg/video.mjpg"));
    //QMediaContent *mc = new QMediaContent(QUrl::fromLocalFile("/Users/userName/Desktop/marsUni.mp4"));
    mp->setMedia(*mc);
   QVideoWidget *vw = new QVideoWidget(this);
   vw->setMaximumSize(704, 576);
   vw->setMinimumSize(704, 576);

   mp->setVideoOutput(vw);
   this->setCentralWidget(vw);
   vw->show();
   mp->play();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

If I uncomment the line containing QUrl::fromLocalFile, I can display the local file. If I open a network connection in VLC pointing to http://96.10.1.168/mjpg/video.mjpg, I can display the camera stream.
I am on Mac OS 10.9.

Why cant I stream the video from the IP camera?
Any comments or debugging suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use the QNetworkRequest constructor to access an HTTP resource.

The specification for this is in the documentation for the QMediaContent constructor:

> **QMediaContent::QMediaContent(const QNetworkRequest & request)**
>
> Constructs a media content with request providing a reference to the
>   content.
>
> This constructor can be used to reference media content via network
>   protocols such as HTTP. This may include additional information
>   required to obtain the resource, such as Cookies or HTTP headers.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediacontent.html#QMediaContent-3

Comment: Castim, did this work? Does this answer resolve your query?