# Playing a network streaming video using Qt MultiMedia and Widgets

Tags: c++, qt, video

I am trying to build a simple qt application which will play a live video stream. The streaming video is not playing in my app. I have played a local file using qt but i can't play the live video stream. I have found this links but they didn't help me :-

[Play a Live video Stream using Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21448027/play-a-live-video-stream-using-qt)

[Qt Stream IP Camera Video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30494319/qt-stream-ip-camera-video)

Here is the code:-

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtMultimediaWidgets/QVideoWidget>
#include <QtMultimedia/QMediaPlayer>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QMediaPlayer *player = new QMediaPlayer;
    QMediaContent *mc=new QMediaContent(QUrl("http://192.168.42.129:8080/video"));
    player->setMedia(*mc);
    player->setVolume(50);
    QVideoWidget *videoWidget = new QVideoWidget;
    videoWidget->resize(700,700);
    videoWidget->show();
    player->setVideoOutput(videoWidget);
    player->play();

    qDebug()<<player->availableMetaData()<<player->currentMedia().canonicalUrl();
    qDebug()<<player->errorString();

    return a.exec();
}
```

I am using an app in my android phone to stream the video. The streamed video is playing on VLC media player, Opera Browser, Mozilla Browser. I have tried different formats like MOV, MKV, WEBM (The app says MP4 is not supported by the hardware renderer in my phone). Please help, stuck on it for a while.

**EDIT -** I don't want to use any other library like libVLC because I noticed the streaming video is lagging in vlc media player. It may have some performance issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out a way around. I was not able to do with QMultimedia widgets. I had to use external libraries like [libvlc](https://wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC/) or [vlc-qt](https://vlc-qt.tano.si). They have good APIs and generally have no performance issues (as I thought previously). They are very easy to integrate with Qt(and its widgets).

Comment: Hi, do you have a tutorial for this one which I can follow? I would like to build it for Mac and Ubuntu.

Comment: Do you have a tutorial? I'm having a lot of problems using VisualStudio or QTCreator