# Playback custom stream with QMediaPlayer

Tags: c++, qt

I searched thoroughly to find an answer to my problem but no other post has been helpful so far.
I am developing an application in Qt where I need to playback a video stream which is received through a custom protocol. I found myself trying in every possible way to feed these packets in QMediaPlayer with no success. My idea was to write incoming packets in a QBuffer and then read them from QMediaPlayer. Follows my trial:

```
/// VideoPlayer.h
class VideoPlayer : public QWidget
{
public slots:
    void play();
    void handlePacket(QByteArray);
    [...]

private:
    QMediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    QBuffer      buffer;
};

/// VideoPlayer.cpp
VideoPlayer::VideoPlayer(QWidget *parent)
: QWidget(parent)
, mediaPlayer(0, (QMediaPlayer::StreamPlayback))
{
    buffer.open(QBuffer::ReadWrite);
}

void VideoPlayer::handlePacket(QByteArray packet)
{
    buffer.buffer().append(packet);
}

void VideoPlayer::play()
{
    mediaPlayer.setMedia(QMediaContent(), &buffer);
    mediaPlayer.play();
}
```

With the above QMediaPlayer plays back data in the buffer at the moment of calling `mediaPlayer.setMedia(QMediaContent(), &buffer)` but seems to ignore that new packets were appended to the buffer. May it be because I am accessing the internal QByteArray directly (I checked that QIODevice::readyRead signal is emitted and it is)? I found no way to make QMediaPlayer play new incoming data other than calling setMedia again. Is there a way to notify QMediaPlayer that media length has changed?

Is there an easier way to make this? I thought about writing my own QIODevice or somehow integrate my packet receiver in the Qt framework to provide my custom stream as a QMediaContent?

Are there any other libraries or methods which would allow me to accomplish this task?

I am using Qt 5.4.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i play a stream with QMediaPlayer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30507317/how-do-i-play-a-stream-with-qmediaplayer)

Comment: Can you provide more info on what type of media is being played (container/raw RTP or UDP/...). My guess is that since various formats have  packet boundaries maybe you are skipping some data that tells the media player new data is available? Anyhow subclassing QIODevice sounds like a good approach.

Answer (score 1):

**My answer is not real answer, just sharing my experience and research results. This focused on audio part of stream.**

I'm currently working with kind of same issue. I have custom protocol which contains one encoded image and one encoded audio portion within one incoming [from network] data frame. I need to handle image and audio separately:

- decode image and send raw RGB data to another process which will display it (lol nevermind)
- play audio portion whatever way

Main: **i can use only Qt library**. This because libVLC [which i use right now for these things] buffering audio/video and i didn't found any way to disable it and play stream in real-time. I should note that incoming stream is from video camera so i need to play it as real-time as possible.

During my quick research, i've found a way to plays *something*:

```
// init method
{
    // ...
    mPlayer = new QMediaPlayer(this, QMediaPlayer::StreamPlayback);
    mBuffer = new QBuffer(this);
    mBuffer->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
    // ...
}

// trying to play audio portion
void MyCoolPlayer::handleFrameAudio(const QByteArray &audioBlob)
{
    mBuffer->seek(0);
    mBuffer->write(audioBlob);
    mBuffer->seek(0);
    mPlayer->setMedia(QMediaContent(), mBuffer);
    mPlayer->play();
}
```

This plays some distorted sound but at least it plays something.

Also, if you have some audio/video decoder, you can use:

- QPainter::drawImage to draw decoded rgb image data on empty widget
- QAudioOutput to plays decoded pcm audio data

Answer (score 0):

I think that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30507317/how-do-i-play-a-stream-with-qmediaplayer#comment49291717_30507317) is the same question. Read it. But the other user also doesn't find the solution in `Qt` he needed to use the `VLC` library as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problem during creating a POC of playing the video stream with QT/QML. It did not work with QBuffer for me as well. I also tried to append the chunks of the video file to the buffer from another thread during playing. QMediaPlayer played only first chunk and stopped. I assume that this is not correct way to emulate the stream.

**Here are two approaches that worked**

1. Play the stream in QML VideoOutput with C++ QMediaPlayer using the `setMedia(QUrl("http://127.0.0.1:8080"));`  The stream was created by VLC media player using the HTTP to the 8080 port.
2. I've also succeeded in playing the stream created by VLC media player to local file by passing it to QMediaPlayer via
   `setMedia(QMediaContent(), &localFile);`.